# Does Postgres use indexes if casting timestamp to date?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a table with some columns and a column `dt` which is of type `TIMESTAMP`.

I create a (non functional) index on this column.

Then I execute a query

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE
    dt::DATE = NOW()::DATE
```

The question is will Postgres use the index I've created earlier and under which circumstances it will/will not?

I understand that a functional index would cover this case, but does a simple index cover both cases or not when it's a `TIMESTAMP` -> `DATE` type conversion?

EDIT:

performing an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the query tells us it does not use index and performs a `Seq` scan (table with 3+ mil records:

```
Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..192289.92 rows=17043 width=12) (actual time=7.237..2493.496 rows=4928 loops=1)
  Filter: ((dt)::date = (now())::date)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 3397155
Total runtime: 2494.546 ms
```

Let me ask a question differently then, is it possible to make Postgres utilize this index or should I create another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple index will not work in this case; try it with `EXPLAIN`.

What you could do to use the simple index is

```
WHERE dt >= current_date::timestamptz
  AND dt < (current_date + 1)::timestamptz
```

I think that this is pretty readable and the best solution, but if you want to go with your current query, you'll have to add a second index on `(dt::date)`.
Don't forget that every additional index costs space and slows down the performance of data modifying statements.

Comment: That's what I thought, but readability & simplicity of queries is really hindered by this. (Please see my edit)

Comment: I disagree, but I have added what you would have to do if you don't want to modify your query.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, yes, the only solution is the obvious one.